# Como se livrar de uma linha vertical no editor do Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

to inciando agr em Python e to usando o pycharm, e logo depois de abrir o editor e tem uma linha na vertical, **COMO** eu me livro dessa bagaça?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Aquela linha é pra te auxiliar, afinal, o pycharm tem uma integração com a pep8 e se não me engano, aquilo representa o tamanho máximo que uma linha deve ter de acordo com a pep8, e quando aquela linha é ultrapassada ele mostra formas de quebrar a linha e deixar o código mais clean. De qualquer forma espero ter exclarecido...

"PEP 8, às vezes escrito PEP8 ou PEP-8, é um documento que fornece diretrizes e práticas recomendadas sobre como escrever código Python. ... O foco principal do PEP 8 é melhorar a legibilidade e a consistência do código Python. PEP significa Python Enhancement Proposal, e há vários deles."

Comment: Aaaaaa então é isso, muito obrigado:)

Comment: se ajudou, da um upvote na minha resposta pra ajudar :)